# Android ActionBarSherlock - How can I change a theme for API <3.0 and the same on API >=3.0

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

I did a new theme on my app, that the parent is Theme.Sherlock.Light. On devices with API <3.0 the changes are working, but when the app is running on devices >=3.0 (in this case is 4.0.3) my new Style isn't working, still using the original Theme.Sherlock.Light.

How can I make an xml style that affects the style in a device with API <3.0 and the same on the devices >=3.0?

Comment: post your all styles.xml code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ActionBarSherlock, you need to declare your styles twice: once *with*, and once *without* the `android:`-prefix.

See the examples here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

Comment: Great, then mark the answer as accepted! Else people will keep looking here thinking the question is unanswered.

Comment: I tried, but I can't "thumbs" up on any answer, because of my low reputation. I need 15 of reputation for "thumbs" up.

Comment: Ohh acctualy I can, I thought was the up arrow that you refering.